# Unity 2D - OnMouseDown() not working

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

When clicking a UI image I made, the 'void OnMouseDown()' function do not work!
Things I have tried:

1. List item
2. put it in a canvas
3. reimporting assets
4. setting z to -1
5. setting box collider in the good size
6. setting box collider 3D instead of 2d
   None of this worked for me, please help me!

My script:

```
public class btnPlay : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler {

    Vector3 pos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        pos = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 4.6f, Screen.height / 1.58f, -1f);
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData p) {
        Debug.Log ("X");
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Level");
    }
}
```

Comment: its `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData)` for UI (actually the EventSystem behind the new UI). if your UI element in question doesnt provide OnPointerDown out of the box, you can implement the `IPointerDownHandler` interface which is found in `UnityEngine.EventSystems` (its really easy, it only sounds complicated)

Comment: When I am adding the Interface I am getting this error in unity:
*`btnPlay' does not implement interface member `UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.OnPointerDown(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData)' and the best implementing candidate `btnPlay.OnPointerDown(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData)' in not public*
btnPlay is the gameObject the script is attached to

Comment: make it public. but if its a button, why not use a button? it has all that an you can just assign a target in the inspector.

Comment: @yes Thanks it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added the interface `IPointerDownHandler` and `using UnityEngine.EventSystems`
than, I changed the method to `public`.
Thanks to @yes for providing the answer